# Mocks for AWS SimpleWorkflowService and ElasticMapReduce

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-web-services, mocking, emr, amazon-swf

Are there any mocks for AWS SWF or EMR available anywhere? I tried looking at some other AWS API mocks such as https://github.com/atlassian/localstack/ or https://github.com/treelogic-swe/aws-mock but they don't have SWF or EMR which are the things that would be really painful to reproduce. Just not sure if anyone has heard of a way to locally test things that use dependencies on those services.

Answer (score 1):

The "moto" project (https://github.com/spulec/moto) groups mocks for the "boto" library (the official python sdk for AWS), and it has mocks for basic things in SWF (disclaimer: I'm the author who contributed them) and EMR.

If you happen to work in Python they're ready to use via a @mock_swf decorator (use 0.4.x for boto 2.x or 1.x for boto 3.x). If you work with another language, moto supports a server mode that mimics an AWS endpoint. The SWF service is not provided out of the box yet, but with a minor change in "moto/backends.py" you should be able to try using it. I think the EMR service works out of the box.

Should you have any issue with the SWF mocks in this project, you can file an issue on the Github project, don't hesitate to cc me directly (@jbbarth), I can probably help improving this.